# Google chrome wont display SVG search icon, but the SVG background is OK

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have a SVG background, that looks find in both FF & chrome, but my search icon, is OK in the FF and wont display in chrome. Both SVGs load from external CSS stylesheet.

Here is a shot: http://imgs.ir/imgs/201308/svg.png

Let me know if a Jsfiddle needed.

Comment: Are you viewing the pages locally or via a web server?

Comment: Both, can't see that SVG icon in chrome in the web server & in my computer.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JnnGg/